# Can you edit a stored query in Amazon Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

In Athena Query Editor, you can click "Save as" to save your query. If you click "Saved queries", you can see all your previous queries and launch them. But you can end up with multiple saved queries with the same name and description, as new saves don't overwrite existing ones with the same name. You can delete an existing saved query, but it is cumbersome to have to open multiple queries with the same name, just to decide which is the oldest, since they don't have dates to tell them apart.

Is there a way to edit a saved query? Or is there some other place to manage these queries that I am simply missing?

Comment: No, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: That feature is not available at the moment. Hoping AWS will pick this use case and provide solution.

Comment: Looks like Athena lacks this quite basic feature so far. I'm wondering if there's a way to send a request to the Athena team...